# Does $A$ and $(A+I)^{-1}$ commute for positive operator $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $A$ is a bounded positive operator ($A \geqslant 0$) on some Hilbert space. Can I say that $A$ and $(A+I)^{-1}$ commute?

Comment: In general, any "rational function" on $A$ will commute with $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "rational function" in sense that $\frac{P(A)}{Q(A)}$ interpret like $P(A) (Q(A))^{-1}$?

Comment: Exactly, or $(Q(A))^{-1}P(A)$ if you prefer

Comment: I think that the reason for making $A$ a positive operator in the context of this question is that it guarantees the invertibility of $(A + I)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I suppose that is the reason.

Comment: $A(A+I)=(A+I)A$. Multiply left and right by $(A+I)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I was thinking that I understand, but why from $A\geq 0$ we have that $(A+I)^{-1}$ exists? I was thinking something like $A+I$ is self-adjoint and $\| (A+I) f\| \geq \|f\|$ for all $f$ in this Hilbert space, so $A+I$ is bounded from bellow. I am using next: if for some $T \in B(H)$ are $T$ and $T^*$ bounded from bellow, then $T$ and $T^*$ are invertible. Maybe (if this is correct answer) there is simpler solution?

Comment: It is a theorem that all positive operators have non-negative spectra. Note that $A+I$ *fails* to be invertible iff $-1$ is in the spectrum of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, that is fine way to look at this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
A(A + I)^{-1} = (A + I - I)(A + I)^{-1}\\
 = (A + I)(A + I)^{-1} - I(A + I)^{-1}\\
= (A + I)^{-1}(A+I) - (A + I)^{-1}I\\
 = (A + I)^{-1}(A+I-I)\\
= (A + I)^{-1}A
$$
since $(A + I)$ commutes with its own inverse, and $I$ commutes with anything.